# Why does the AVC Decoder Config Record ISO 14496-15:2004 5.2.4.1.1 use arrays of multiple Sequence and Parameter Sets?

Tags: video, mp4, h.264

Why does the AVC Decoder Config Record ISO 14496-15:2004 5.2.4.1.1 use arrays of multiple Sequence and Parameter Sets?

It seems logical that you may have multiple different configurations in one track but how is the configuration for a specific period of time referenced in this index?  Is there something in the H.264 spec which defines this or is it specific to the MP4 container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sample Description Index (one based) is used to choose the correct AVC Decoder Config Record.
For any given sample you look up the index in your MP4 file 'stbl' -> 'stsc' -> entry[].sample_description_index. Based on the sample_description_index you choose the AVC Decoder Config Record.
An AVC Decoder Config Record can contain multiple PPS and SPS. The slice header of a video coding unit inside the AVC stream contains the `pic_parameter_set_id` that references the correct PPS. The PPS contains `seq_parameter_set_id` referencing the correct SPS.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but that does not reference the index within the Decoder Config Record itself since each Decoder Config Record may contain multiple Sequence and Picture Parameter Sets.  I believe you are referring to the index within the SampleDescriptionBox.

Comment: I edited my answer on how multiple PPS and SPS are referenced from the AVC stream.

Comment: Have any idea if that is actually used in production or is it limited to some use case like SVC?  Codec transitions, such in MPEG-TS, simply overrides any existing PPS / SPS and resets the index to 0.

Comment: I doubt you'll see many MP4 files in the wild containing multiple SPS/PPS. I don't have much experience with SVC.